# Facebook Graph API - access token for offline access (deprecation)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get my head round Facebook's recent deprecation of offline_access with access tokens. I'm using a JS plugin called neosmart FB Wall, which uses an AJAX call, with the access token appended, to request wall data. As I understand it and from just testing this morning, now if the Facebook user logs out, a new access token will be required and the previous one will be invalidated.

So basically I think I have to extend the plugin so that it checks the response from Facebook and if necessary, sends login credentials to request a new access token. The slightly confusing thing for me is that I have 5 sites which have been using the same plugin for over a year, and none of them have had any issues yet with the access token expiring, even though the Facebook accounts have been logged in and out of several times! Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening here? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What actually you do with FB API? `offline_access` wasn't required for 99% actions.

Comment: It's just read only, getting wall posts for display. I thought offline_access was required for accessing the feed with  an access token which didn't need to be updated

Answer (score 0):

Since offline_access is deprecated you can create a long-life Facebook Access token. The developers of fb.wall released a new plugin: neosmart STREAM - the offical successor of fb.wall - This plugin contains a Facebook Access Token Creator which creates long-life access tokens. Project website: https://neosmart-stream.de